# Topological version of uniform convergence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, functions

We have a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ on a Banach space $X$ and $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for each $x\in X$ as $n\to\infty$. Given an open ball $B\subset X$ and $\epsilon>0$, we want to show that there exists another open ball $B_0\subset B$ and $m\geq 1$ such that $|f_m(x)-f(x)|\leq \epsilon$, for all $x\in B_0$.

My approach: Let $Y$ be a closed ball in $B$, fix $\epsilon>0$ and consider $E_l=\{x\in Y| \sup_{j,k\geq l} |f_j(x)-f_k(x)|< \epsilon\}$. **(Please check the following!)** Then $E_l$ is open for each $l$: this is because for any $x\in E_l$, take the radius $r$ and corresponding ball $B_r(x)$, such that both $d(f_j(x),f_j(x'))$ and $d(f_k(x),f_k(x'))<\delta/2$ where $\delta=\epsilon-\sup_{j,k\geq l} |f_j(x)-f_k(x)|$ (by taking the minimum $r$ at $x$ for $f_j$ and $f_k$), and therefore, we have $$\sup_{j,k\geq l} |f_j(x')-f_k(x')|=|f_{j'}(x')-f_{k'}(x')|$$ where $j', k'$ corresponds to the indices in the family $\{f_n\}$ corresponding to the supremum at the point $x'$, then $$\leq |f_{j'}(x')-f_{j'}(x)+f_{j'}(x)-f_{k'}(x)+f_{k'}(x)-f_{k'}(x')|\leq \delta + \sup_{j,k\geq l}|f_j(x)-f_k(x)|< \epsilon$$

Then, notice that $E_1\subseteq E_2\subseteq E_3\dots$ and that $Y=\cup_{l=1}^\infty E_l$. To prove this, take $(\cup_{l=1}^\infty E_l)^c=\cap_{l=1}^\infty E_l^c=\cap_{l=1}^\infty\{x\in Y: \dots \geq \epsilon \}=\varnothing$ by pointwise convergence of $f_n$ (for any $x$, there is an $L$ such that for $l\geq L$, $x\notin E_l^c$. Now, I'm thinking that from this, the conclusion should follow but it feels like I'm missing something. We've covered Baire Category Theorem in class, and I'm sure this plays into the proof (at a higher level, whereas my approach is more bottom-up), but I'm unsure how to proceed and would therefore appreciate any help and/or feedback on my attempt.

Notes:

- Recall a Baire space is a topological space such that the intersection of countably many dense open sets is still dense
- Recall Baire Category Theorem: Let $(X,\rho)$ be a complete metric space, then 1) if $\{U_n\}_1^\infty$ is an open dense set in $X$, then $\cap_{n=1}^\infty \bar{U_n}=X$, and also 2) $X$ is not meager. The version of BCT below follows from this.
- $A_l$ is clearly closed because for any $n$ and $x\in A_l$, $\cdots\leq \epsilon$, so $f(x)\leq \epsilon$ for any $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Your $E_l$ is not necessarily open(the final result you try to prove is equivalent to that one of $E_l$ has nonempty interior). The first equality $$\sup_{j,k\geq l} |f_j(x')-f_k(x')|=|f_{j'}(x')-f_{k'}(x')|$$ makes no sense. For example, take $f_n=x^n$ on $[0,1]$, then there is always an annoying isolated point $1$ in every $E_l$. But it is true that the union of $E_l$ is the $Y$. So the following argument still works after some minor modification.

Baire Category Theorem says in complete metric space, if we have a sequence of closed sets $A_j$ with empty interior, then $\bigcup_j A_j$ also has empty interior.

$E_l(\epsilon)=\{x\in Y| \sup_{j,k\geq l} |f_j(x)-f_k(x)|< \epsilon\}$. Since $Y=\bigcup \bar E_l(\epsilon /2)$ has nonempty interior, by Baire Category Theorem, at least one of $\bar E_l(\epsilon /2)$, say $\bar E_m$ contains an open ball $B_0$ in $Y$ . But $B_0\subset\bar E_m(\epsilon /2)\subset E_m(\epsilon)$. Thus in $B_0$, $|f_j-f_k|<\epsilon$ whenever $j,k\geq m$, thus we also have $|f_j-f|\leq \epsilon$ for $j\geq m$.

Rmk. Note that $A_l(\epsilon)=\{x\in Y| \sup_{j,k\geq l} |f_j(x)-f_k(x)|\leq \epsilon\}$ is clearly closed, and $\bar E_l(\epsilon/2) \subset A_l(\epsilon/2) \subset E_l(\epsilon)$. In fact, the proof will be more smooth if we consider $A_l$ and its interior instead of $E_l$ at the very beginning.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense. If you have the time, could you please double-check my proof attempt above, in particular my claim that $E_l$ could be open and my reasoning behind it?

Comment: Could you explain what is your $j’,k’$ and why can you find a minimum $r$?

Comment: Oh, your counter-example is correct, thanks! My main error was assuming that the $j', k'$ corresponding to the supremum would somehow be finite, when they can indeed be each taken to infinity

Comment: Also, I understand that by construction, $B_0\subset \bar{E}_m(\epsilon/2)$ and by openness, $B_0\subset E_m(\epsilon)$, but how is $\bar{E}_m(\epsilon/2)\subset E_m(\epsilon)$?

Comment: @mtcicero: See the Rmk. How would you get $B_0\subset E_m$ simply by openness?

Comment: Alright thanks! The closed $A_l$ clarifies it.